# Find$\{a_{n}\}$such that $a_{n+1}=\frac{a_{n}^{2}+3}{a_{n}+1},\,a_{1}=1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

I met the following problem when I explained some math problems to a high school student.Find$\{a_{n}\}$such that $$a_{n+1}=\frac{a_{n}^{2}+3}{a_{n}+1},\,a_{1}=1.$$ Rewrite $$a_{n+1}=\frac{a_{n}^{2}+3}{a_{n}+1}$$ as $$(a_{n}+A)(a_{n}-a_{n+1}+B)=0$$,but I don't have $A$ and $B$ that satisfy the conditions.

$3=\frac{3^2+3}{3+1}$, but $a_{1}=1$.

$a_{n+1}-3=\frac{a_{n}(a_{n}-3)}{a_{n}+1}$ doesn't seem work.

Could anyone help me, thanks a lot.

Comment: Have look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2873158/find-a-formula-for-the-sequence-a-n-if-a-1-1-and-a-n1-fraca-n23a-n

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but it doesn't fit in a comment.  The first few values of $a_n$ are:
$$
1\\
2\\
7/3\\
38/15\\
2119/795\\
3193118/1158315\\
14221083479599/5040330115395\\
139226999175098461748609438/48541941503963464907166315\\
26453117554225500188222788581576818186109055874713519/9114668934704209925639212726593462750208755315360195
$$
I doubt there's a compact formula for $a_n.$

Comment: @Zuo It's easy to show that it converges to $3$, but you asked for a formula for $a_n.$

Comment: Just curious, why do you doubt that?

Comment: @Ovi Because of the examples given above.  Look at the explosive growth of the numerators and denominators.  I admit it's possible that there's a compact formula, I just think it's unlikely.

Comment: @saulspatz Right. I'd rather have an expression for $n$， although it might not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you may actually want the equation
$\ (a_{n}+A)(a_{n}-a_{n+1}+B)=C \ $ in which case the solution is
$\ (a_{n}+1)(a_{n}-a_{n+1}-1)=-4. \ $ By definition we have
$\ (a_n+1)a_{n+1} = a_n^2+3. \ $ Now $\ (a_n+1)(a_n-1) = a_n^2-1 \ $
and subtracting the two equations gives the solution you want.

Note that if $\ a_n \to 3\ $ then $\ (a_n + 1) \to 4\ $ and
$\ (a_{n}-a_{n+1}-1) \to -1\ $ which is consistent with
$\ (a_{n}+1)(a_{n}-a_{n+1}-1)=-4.$

You wrote:

> $a_{n+1}-3=\frac{a_{n}(a_{n}-3)}{a_{n}+1}$ doesn't seem work.

but it does work. It implies that as $\ a_n\to 3\ $ the ratio
$\ \frac{a_n}{a_n+1} \to \frac34<1\ $ and the sequence $\ a_n\ $
[converges linearly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_convergence)
to $3.$